# How to send message to multiple numbers using Service?

Tags: java, android, service, smsmanager

I want to send message to multiple numbers. I tried to use SMS manager. But it's not working.

I am doing it `onPostExecute` method of an `AsyncTask`. But I want to create a service and send messages from that service because user can close the application before messages sending gets complete so it should be working in background.

I have created a arraylist of numbers. Now this I want to send to service and send message to each number.

**My attempt:**

```
@Override
public void doPostExecute(JSONArray response) throws JSONException {

    ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject subObject1 = response.getJSONObject(i);

        String status = subObject1.getString("status");

        if (status.equals("1")) {

            JSONObject invitation = subObject1.getJSONObject("invitation");

            String number = invitation.getString("invitee_no");

            numbers.add(number);
        } else {

        }
    }

    try {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        PendingIntent sentPI;
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";

        sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(InviteContactsActivity.this, 0,new Intent(SENT), 0);

        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, null);
        sms.sendTextMessage("8655864341", null, "Hi,add me to your unique contact list.",sentPI, null);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have added permission for send sms in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

How can I do this? Can anyone help please? Thank you..

EDIT:

I tried to write service like below:

```
    public class MessageService extends Service {

    ArrayList<String>  numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        numbers = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("numbers");

        for(int i=0;i<numbers.size();i++) {

            sendMsg(numbers.get(i));
        }

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public void sendMsg(final String num){
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        final PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MessageService.this, 0,new Intent(SENT), 0);
        Handler h = new Handler();
        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                sms.sendTextMessage("8655864341", null, "Hi MyApp SMS", sentPI, null);
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {

    //    numbers = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("numbers");

        return null;
    }
}
```

And calling it from an activity:

```
       Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this,MessageService.class);
    serviceIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("numbers",numbers);
    startService(serviceIntent);
```

Added service in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<receiver android:name=".SmsSentReceiver"/> <receiver android:name=".SmsDeliveredReceiver"/>

<service android:name=".helper.MessageService"></service>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Activities.MainActivity" />
```

But as I do debug and check service is not getting called.

What's going wrong?

EDIT :

Tried this way with broadcast receiver :

```
public class MessageService extends Service {

ArrayList<String>  numbers = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    numbers = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("numbers");

    for (String number:numbers) {


        sendSMS("8655864341","Hello");
    }


      //  sendMsg(numbers.get(i));


    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

public void sendMsg(final String num){
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    final PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MessageService.this, 0,new Intent(SENT), 0);
    Handler h = new Handler();
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sms.sendTextMessage("7303668514", null, "Hi MyApp SMS", sentPI, null);
        }
    }, 2000);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{

//    numbers = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("numbers");

    return null;
}

private void sendSMS (String phoneNumber, String message){
    ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentPendingIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
    ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveredPendingIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0,
            new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SmsSentReceiver.class), 0);
    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0,
            new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SmsDeliveredReceiver.class), 0);
    try {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        ArrayList<String> mSMSMessage = sms.divideMessage(message);
        for (int i = 0; i < mSMSMessage.size(); i++) {
            sentPendingIntents.add(i, sentPI);
            deliveredPendingIntents.add(i, deliveredPI);
        }
        sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, mSMSMessage,
                sentPendingIntents, deliveredPendingIntents);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sending failed...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}


public class SmsDeliveredReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(context, "SMS delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Toast.makeText(context, "SMS not delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
}

public class SmsSentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                Toast.makeText(context, "SMS generic failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                Toast.makeText(context, "SMS no service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                Toast.makeText(context, "SMS null PDU", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                Toast.makeText(context, "SMS radio off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Getting this exception:

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.siddhi.contactsapp.helper.MessageService$SmsSentReceiver: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.example.siddhi.contactsapp.helper.MessageService$SmsSentReceiver has no zero argument constructor
```

Not getting message..

Comment: Sid See my Edit

Comment: declare your Service and Broadcast Recever inside <application></application> tags like Activity

Comment: okk service is started sendTextMessage gets execute but not getting the message.. :-( @AshishShukla

Comment: I think you have to add another pending intent for DELIVERY and a Broadcast Receiver for the same and send another SMS after first is deliverd ...look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578689/sending-text-messages-programmatically-in-android

Comment: First try to send SMS for two numbers and declare permission for RECEIVE_SMS.... follow this tutorial http://web.archive.org/web/20150303013635/http://mobiforge.com/design-development/sms-messaging-android

Comment: Exception is bcoz you have not initialized and registered your Receiver

Comment: is it fine initializing like this:      IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        this.registerReceiver(smsDeliveredReceiver, filter);
        filter = new IntentFilter();
        this.registerReceiver(smsSentReceiver, filter); ?@AshishShukla

Comment: filter = new IntentFilter();  dont do this again OR you can Register Receiver directly without need to add it in Manifest like registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }
} , new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124990/discussion-between-ashish-shukla-and-sid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this :

Use a for loop for your Numbers list and inside that **Use a handler** to maintain some time gap between each sent message, say 2 seconds and send the message.

OR

You can define a **Broadcast Receiver inside your Service** which will check for the Message Delivery Report and if Delivered then send another Message.

[First Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394985/implement-broadcast-receiver-inside-service)

[Second Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140086/how-to-get-delivery-report-for-sent-text-message)

Hope it Helps :)

**Edit :**

```
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    ArrayList<String> numberlist=new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i=0;i<numberlist.size();i++) {

        sendMsg(numberlist.get(i));
    }

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

public void sendMsg(final String num){
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    final PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyService.this, 0,new Intent(SENT), 0);
    Handler h = new Handler();
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sms.sendTextMessage(num, null, "Hi MyApp SMS", sentPI, null);
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: can you please show me an example of sending message using handler in service? @Ashish Shukla

Comment: can I test sending message on geny motion emulator? @Ashish Shukla

Comment: Yes but only in paid versions

Comment: can you help me with this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39852101/object-is-not-getting-removed-from-list-oncheckedchange-listener-of-check-box/39852227?noredirect=1#comment67019418_39852227 ?@Ashish Shukla

Comment: My pleasure Yes Sure

Answer (score 0):

try to send SMS OnPost Method or run your AsynTask on Main Thread.
follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4918811/2032058) its help you